# Aurelia ref binding scoped different based on element?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm confused about the scope of the [`ref`](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/5) attribute/binding. I have two HTML tables that have the same `ref="activeTable"` and each table has multiple rows that all have the same `ref="activeRow"`.

See this [GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=db499218b51e769d6208993f70ea535b) (code copied below).

When I click on a row's Edit button, the reference to the clicked row gets passed in (regardless of the table or row clicked). But when I click on a table's Add button, the reference to Table B **always** gets passed in.

**Why is `ref` being overwritten for `activeTable` but not `activeRow`?**

My current solution is to use `ref="activeTableA"` or `ref="activeTableB"`, but I still want to understand what is going on.

I suspect it has something to do with the the `repeat` and/or `click.delegate`. Maybe the event listener is being added to a different scope for the tables and the rows?

---

## HTML

```html
<template>
  <h4>Table A</h4>
  <!-- Note the table ref -->
  <table id="tableA" ref="activeTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Foo</th>
      <!-- Passing in table ref -->
      <th><button click.delegate="addRow(activeTable)">Add</button></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <!-- Note the row ref -->
      <tr repeat.for="foo of foos" ref="activeRow">
        <td class="editable-cell">${foo.id}</td>
        <!-- Passing in row ref -->
        <td><button click.delegate="editRow(activeRow)">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h4>Table B</h4>
  <table id="tableB" ref="activeTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bar</th>
      <th><button click.delegate="addRow(activeTable)">Add</button></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="bar of bars" ref="activeRow">
        <td class="editable-cell">${bar.id}</td>
        <td><button click.delegate="editRow(activeRow)">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

## JS

```js
export class App {
  foos = [
    {id: 0},
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4},
    {id: 5},
    {id: 6},
    {id: 7},
    {id: 8},
    {id: 9},
  ];

  bars = [
    {id: 10},
    {id: 11},
    {id: 12},
    {id: 13},
    {id: 14},
    {id: 15},
    {id: 16},
    {id: 17},
    {id: 18},
    {id: 19},
  ];

  addRow(table) {
    console.log("Adding tow to", table);
  }

  editRow(row) {
    console.log('Editing', row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ref` allows you to reference an element as a variable on your Binding Context. Typically, your binding context and your page's (or custom element's) view-model are one and the same. But when you're dealing with a "template controller" (behaviors that add/remove DOM elements) such as `repeat.for`, the binding context can be changed. In the case of `repeat.for`, the binding context becomes the specific *item* for this iteration of the repeater.

So you're overwriting the `activeTable` property on your page's VM, but the `activeRow` property is being attached to each item in `foos` and each item in `bars`. This is actually the behavior you want (regarding `activeRow`) because you can pass the specific element for that row to the function on the page VM. And for `activeTable`, you'll need to use different names for each table ref.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it was something to do with the repeat scope. You've been extremely helpful in my Aurelia development here and elsewhere, very appreciated!